# Solid State Variable AC

Tags: ac, control

At work I often need a variable AC source and I usually use a large variable transformer which gives me anywhere from 1 to 300VAC. Total power output is 2kW or less.

I do a lot of testing and was looking for methods to control the AC voltage level remotely. My backup plan is to use a stepper motor to physically turn the variac knob for me and control the voltage that way, but I wanted to know if there were any other methods.

I have seen SSR and TRIAC circuits that do something similar, but I want to maintain the sinusoidal shape of the AC waveform. Any suggestions?

Comment: A geared or pulley ratio driven stepper will be your cheapest solution as programmable voltage pure sine sources can be several k$/k unless you simply by a VFD.

Answer (score 1):

I designed and built a circuit that does exactly this, although at a lower output power level as a prototype. It consists of two pairs of NMOS or IGBT devices connected with gates and sources in parallel, and the drains are connected as a sort of half-bridge. The gates are driven with a complementary PWM signals for 0 to 100%, at about 20 kHz. Here is a simulation showing the concept.
[image: PWM Vernier simulation]

This is what the prototype looks like. There are two simple DC-DC converters supplying isolated 12 VDC for gate drive, which are done by means of optoisolators.
[image: PWM Vernier prototype]

Here is a scope image of the input and output waveforms, through a low pass R-C filter:
[image: PWM Vernier waveforms]

Answer (score 0):

The instruments of this kind are readily available. An example is [California Instruments model 2001RP](https://www.testequity.com/products/1246/). It is rated for 2kW output, with voltage varying from 0 to 300V AC, and it can generate waves from 16 Hz to 5 kHz, all for a reasonable cost under $4,000. 
See [specifications here](http://www.programmablepower.com/ac-power-source/RP/Specifications.htm). It will take some engineering effort to build this one by yourself.

Comment: We have several of them (not that particular model), just not that I can claim as my own for my bench.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable low-budget approach if you can't swing for a $4k supply and have the spare parts around. A few things to watch out for:

- Your motor may have a lot of torque and you risk overdriving the stops on the variac/transformer knob. Ensure you do not damage it by using a belt, or a low-torque motor. Don't count on dead reckoning to know your position as the stepper will (hopefully) stall at the end stops. You could use limit switches also, but you'll find alignment will be difficult without proper fixturing.
- Do not assume the output is safe at any time unless all power is removed. Your software may have a bug that causes the voltage to increase when you're not expecting, so don't assume you can touch the output when it's set at a low voltage.
- You'll want a voltmeter on the output for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Any class D audio amplifier - these days they can be single chip - coupled to a step-up transformer will do this job well. You don't need to actually make the amplifier - you can buy plenty of ready-made mW-range to multi-kW high efficiency audio amplifiers. Add a transformer on the output and you're done.

There's some competition in the basic audio market (as opposed to "audophile"), so the prices are reasonable and it's highly unlikely that the cost of an amplifier+transformer will be higher than that of a solid-state variable AC supply. High power PA amplifiers drive outputs at almost line levels so the step-up ratio may end up being close to  1 or just 1 - in that case no transformer needed.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate and expand upon the design that uses a motorized variable [auto]transformer, I offer this assembly, which consists of a synchronous (Superior Slo-Syn) motor driven by a solid state triac module and a PIC circuit that allows for quick stepping at about 1% of full rotation, as well as a "semi-latch" mode that can traverse the entire 330 degrees in just a few seconds. This feature, IMHO, is "superior" to Superior Electric's motorized Powerstats or Variacs, which can take over 30 seconds for full traversal.

Here are some images of the ETI PI-4000B test set which can drive over 50,000 amperes through a circuit breaker for an instantaneous trip test (< 100 msec). More details available on request.

[image: Motor drive assembly]

[image: PI-4000B]

[image: PI-4000 test sets]